# getting field values from datatables

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a generic function which extracts a datatable from a query.

I want to loop through the datatable, extracing the values from the datatable.
I have two fields, ID and BrandName.

How do I loop through the datatable pulling through the ID numbers and the BrandType names?

Comment: did the answers were useful to you? if so, you should mark an answer as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need something very much like this:

```
    DataTable result = new FunctionThatReturnsDataTable();
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    foreach (DataRow row in result.Rows)
    {
        myObject.ID = Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"].ToString());
        myObject.BrandName = row["BrandName"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach(var row in dt.Rows)
{
  var id = (int)row["ID"];
  var brandName = (string)row["BrandName"];
}
```